# MySql using MD5 more efficently

Tags: php, mysql, database-administration

i got a table that contain between 10-20 million records(MYISAM engine)
i need to run on the table key field the md5 function.
this takes a lot of time and sometimes 10-12 hours, that is because the md5 function slows down the server and use 99.99% I/O.
is there a way to make it better by mysql defenitions?
or is there a better way of giving a unique value to a string in a different way than md5 that is more efficent?

Thank you

Comment: So how are you doing this at the moment? And note that MD5 will not guarantee a unique value. But if it's a key field; try dropping the index before running the update, then recreating the index again afterwards

Comment: Hi i'm doing a simple "UPDATE table SET column = MD5(column)" and i already dropped the indexes. the strange thing is that if the table contain 10 millions records it takes about 45 minutes and if it's 14 millions records it takes 10-12 hours